# CSS3 DIV Contenteditable with draggable

Tags: css

I would like to develop a website that has a `div` element which is content editable, and where the `div` element is able to be dragged around. I found the solution here, but after I coded it, it seems like I am missing some plugin, and I failed to find the plugin or framework that needed to be added into my code. Can anyone please help?

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="d">
  <span>Text to edit</span>
</div>

$("#d").draggable()
.click(function () {
  $(this).draggable({
    disabled: false
  });
}).dblclick(function () {
  $(this).draggable({
    disabled: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you add jQuery UI reference? Any errors in the console?

Comment: thanks for reply. the link u provided i did it before but in my case i need to highlight the text inside. like this http://jsfiddle.net/brPsk/. but even i include jquery and jqueryUI also not working for me. please help

Comment: Include jQuery and jQuery UI and run your script inside document.ready function like http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/S7AvQ/

Comment: yes it works and really thanks. but there are another issue which when i double click it turn to light color and able to select when i click couple of time then it able me to edit the text normally but cannot select the text.

Comment: Can you use something like: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6L6G8/

Comment: Thanks edward. i fixed that issues. by using http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/222/. you helped me alot! thanks alot!

Comment: do you got any idea how to apply the function for multiple div?

Comment: Yes use class instead of id like http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/281/, I'll post the conversation as answer soon. please remove unuseful comments